# Converting multiple variables into one column and creating a matching values column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, transform

I have a Table with the following format:

| Country | GDP | LifeExp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 6.5 | 75 |
| UK | 9.5 | 78 |
| Italy | 5.5 | 80 |

I need to change the Table above to the format of the Table below. This is just a small part of the actual table so hard coding is not going to cut it unfortunately.

| Country | Indicator name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | GDP | 6.5 |
| USA | LifeExp | 75 |
| UK | GDP | 9.5 |
| UK | LifeExp | 78 |
| Italy | GDP | 5.5 |
| Italy | LifeExp | 80 |

Here is the code to create the first Table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':["USA", "UK", "Italy"],
                  'GDP':[6.5, 9.5, 5.5],
                  'LifeExp':[75,78,80]})
```

I've never uploaded something before on stackoverflow so I hope I've provided sufficient info for someone to help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ``df.melt('Country', var_name='Indicator name')``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), as follows:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='Country', var_name='Indicator name', value_name='Value')
   .sort_values('Country', ascending=False)
).reset_index(drop=True)




# Result

  Country Indicator name  Value
0     USA            GDP    6.5
1     USA        LifeExp   75.0
2      UK            GDP    9.5
3      UK        LifeExp   78.0
4   Italy            GDP    5.5
5   Italy        LifeExp   80.0
```

You can choose sorting order of `Country` column. If you want it in ascending order, you can simply remove the parameter `ascending=False` in the [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) and `.reset_index()`:

```
print(
    df.set_index("Country")
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "Indicator Name", 0: "Value"})
)
```

Prints:

```
  Country Indicator Name  Value
0     USA            GDP    6.5
1     USA        LifeExp   75.0
2      UK            GDP    9.5
3      UK        LifeExp   78.0
4   Italy            GDP    5.5
5   Italy        LifeExp   80.0
```